# Form validation function doesn't run on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that I'm using to validate my form values. I've added it to the `onsubmit` attribute, but it doesn't run when it should. I've put it inside the body and before the submit button, but the page runs the function at the very beginning.

I want for `checkForm` to run at the end to validate the entry of data, but whenever I submit the form, the page just refreshes.

Is my function defined or called in the wrong place? What changes do I need to make to stop the page from refreshing and have my function validate the form data?

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">

  <script>
    function checkForm(form)
    if(radioValue = checkRadio(form.radiofield)) {
      return true;
    else {
      alert("Seleccione un tipo de operación");
      return false;
    }
    return true;        
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you post your function? It may be running the `checkForm` and then continuing to submit the form. You'd have to prevent that from happening in your function if the form has errors

Comment: The location of a function definition shouldn't make a difference, it shouldn't be called until you submit the form.

Comment: If you can post an example of the form fields you're trying to validate, that would also be quite helpful.

Comment: my guess is there is an error in the function. Show it

Comment: What does your console say about that function?

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to accomplish here. You've got a `<form>` tag, but no form inside it. All your `onsubmit` function does is return a `boolean` so I don't see any need for a form, you could just use a `click` event. Where does `radioValue` come from? It's not in the code you provided. Also, the `form.radiofield` isn't valid because there's no such element in your form. And yes, the page refresh will not allow your function to work.

Comment: Also, the function declaration is quite broken. @Ulises, are you coming into JS from a Python background, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preventDefault()` of JS to prevent refresh when submiting

For more detail -> go here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
     $("#form").on('submit', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           // call your function
          $("#form").submit ();
      });
</script>
```

this should work;